# Getting Kivy to update PopUp before finishing execution of function called by button

Tags: python, multithreading, popup, kivy, clock

***About issue:*** In sutPopUp.create(), I am trying to get the popup to update itself (removing it's two buttons and change the "hidden" label). I have tried both threading the update function and calling  `Clock.schedule_once(self.update_txt, -1)`, but neither one has worked. They both seemingly wait for  `run_local_command`, which is just a blocking function that runs a local command. Below is the python code:

```
class sutPopUp(Popup):
    pop_float = ObjectProperty(None)
    sutPopUp_create = ObjectProperty(None)
    sutPopUp_cancel = ObjectProperty(None)
    sut_wait_text = ObjectProperty(None)
    sutPopUp_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, my_widget,**kwargs):
        super(sutPopUp,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = "Test Station Setup"
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (400, 200)

    def create(self, *args):
        self.quick_change_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_txt)
        self.quick_change_thread.start()
        time.sleep(1)

        sut_name = self.sutPopUp_input.text
        create_cmd = "python project.py -c " + sut_name
        create_handle = run_local_command(create_cmd, True, "C:\Project")

        wm.current = "blank"
        wm.remove_widget(screens[2])
        screens[2] = Dashboard(name="dashboard_screen")
        wm.add_widget(screens[2])
        wm.current = "dashboard_screen"

        self.dismiss()
        self.quick_change_thread.join()

    def update_txt(self):
        self.sutPopUp_create.disabled = True
        self.sutPopUp_cancel.disabled = True
        self.pop_float.remove_widget(self.sutPopUp_create)
        self.pop_float.remove_widget(self.sutPopUp_cancel)
        self.sut_wait_text.text = "Creating Test Station ..."
```

Here is the kv:

```
<sutPopUp@Popup>
    pop_float:pop_float
    sutPopUp_create:sutPopUp_create
    sutPopUp_cancel:sutPopUp_cancel
    sut_wait_text:sut_wait_text
    sutPopUp_input:sutPopUp_input

    FloatLayout:
        id: pop_float
        size: root.height, root.width
        Label:
            text: "Enter Test Station Name:"
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.2
        TextInput:
            id: sutPopUp_input
            multiline: False
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":0.7}
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
        Label:
            id: sut_wait_text
            text: ""
            pos_hint:{"x":0.4,"top":0.3}
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.2
        Button:
            id: sutPopUp_create
            text: "Create"
            pos_hint:{"x":0.1,"top":0.3}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release: root.create()

        Button:
            id: sutPopUp_cancel
            text: "Cancel"
            pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"top":0.3}
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: Your `blocking` function is apparently `blocking`. If it does not return, then everything will be blocked. Perhaps your `run_local_command` should be something like `run_local_command_in_another_thread()`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I tried running the local command in another thread, but that doesn't fix the issue. I need the popup to update itself and then wait for the command to finish then switch back to the screen it was on (updated) with the new file created by the local command. So, what I did was setup a thread bool variable in `run_local_command_in_another_thread()` for the main thread to know when the cmd is finished, but that still just blocks the main thread from updating.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Is there a way in kivy to force an popup to update inside of a blocking function? Or, to tell screenmanager to switch screens from inside a thread that is not the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest breaking the `create()` method into three methods. Since the `create()` method is initiated by a `Button` press, it will run on the main thread, so simply call the `update_text()` method directly. Then use another thread to run the `create_cmd`. That new thread then uses `Clock.schedule_once()` to run the remaining code from the original `create()` method (the new `finish_create()` method) back on the main thread.

```
def create(self, *args):
    self.update_text()  # this needs to run on the main thread
    # time.sleep(1)  # ??? this will freeze your app for 1 second

    Thread(target=self.do_create).start()

def do_create(self):
    sut_name = self.sutPopUp_input.text
    create_cmd = "python project.py -c " + sut_name
    create_handle = run_local_command(create_cmd, True, "C:\Project")

    # after above command completes, run the rest of the former create() back on the main thread
    Clock.schedule_once(self.finish_create)

def finish_create(self, dt):
    wm.current = "blank"
    wm.remove_widget(screens[2])
    screens[2] = Dashboard(name="dashboard_screen")
    wm.add_widget(screens[2])
    wm.current = "dashboard_screen"

    self.dismiss()
```

Nothing in the GUI will update while there is a function that is holding the main thread, no matter what you do. So this approach minimizes time spent on the main thread. This code has not been tested, so there may be errors. But I believe this approach should accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you, so much man! That worked!!! I hadn't thought of running clock from inside the thread, so thank you man!!!